# ranking mysql with specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT concours_photo_like.id , COUNT(concours_photo_like.id) AS nb_like , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank 
FROM ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) as r , concours_photo_like
JOIN concours_photo ON concours_photo.id = concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
WHERE concours_photo.id_concours = 67
GROUP BY concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
```

Here the result

```
| id     | nb_like    | rank |
|--------|------------|------|
|    110 |          2 |    2 |
|    104 |          3 |    1 |
|    134 |          1 |    4 |
|    176 |          1 |    5 |
|    113 |          2 |    3 |
```

How can I get the rank for a specific ID for example if I want the rank for the ID 134

I tried something like

```
SELECT concours_photo_like.id , COUNT(concours_photo_like.id) AS nb_like , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank 
FROM ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) as r , concours_photo_like
JOIN concours_photo ON concours_photo.id = concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
WHERE concours_photo.id_concours = 67
AND concours_photo_like.id = 134
GROUP BY concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
```

But the result is

```
| id     | nb_like    | rank |
|--------|------------|------|
|    134 |          1 |    1 |
```

and the result should be 4 for the rank not 1

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL executes the `where` clause before assigning any value to a user variable in the select list.

You either have to filter in the `having` clause or wrap the query into a subquery and filter in the outer query.

Having:

```
SELECT concours_photo_like.id , COUNT(concours_photo_like.id) AS nb_like , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank 
FROM ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) as r , concours_photo_like
JOIN concours_photo ON concours_photo.id = concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
WHERE concours_photo.id_concours = 67
GROUP BY concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
HAVING concours_photo_like.id = 134
```

Subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT concours_photo_like.id , COUNT(concours_photo_like.id) AS nb_like , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank 
     FROM ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) as r , concours_photo_like
     JOIN concours_photo ON concours_photo.id = concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
     WHERE concours_photo.id_concours = 67
     GROUP BY concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
    ) t1
WHERE t1.id = 134
```

Answer (score 2):

How about wrapping your original query with another `SELECT` statement and then filtering by the `id` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT concours_photo_like.id , COUNT(concours_photo_like.id) AS nb_like , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank 
FROM ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) as r , concours_photo_like
JOIN concours_photo ON concours_photo.id = concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo
WHERE concours_photo.id_concours = 67
GROUP BY concours_photo_like.id_concours_photo) AS nb
WHERE nb.id = 134
```

There's likely a more elegant way to perform this query, but this is what is coming to mind right now.